# What belongs in a controller spec and what belongs in a request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rabl

Using Rspec, I am trying to create a controller spec for my API, as well as a request spec. The problem is I don't understand what part of the test goes in each spec.

For simplicity, let's say my controller looks like follows:

```
class Api::V1::ItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:user_id]
      user = User.find(params[:user_id])
      @items = user.items
    else
      @items = Item.all
    end
  end
end
```

It uses RABL to render the response.

For a controller as simple as this, what does the controller spec look like? What does the request spec look like? At what point to I verify that the API response JSON is what I expect? etc.

Answer (score 2):

For the controller spec, I'd write tests like this:

```
it "renders with a user_id" do
  get :index, id: @user.id
  assigns(:items).should == @user.items
  response.should be_success
  response.should render_template("index")
end
```

One for the `user_id` path, and one without.  I leave setting up `@user` to you; you can use fixtures, or FactoryGirl, instantiate one in a before block, or just stub/mock it all out.  It's good to avoid hitting the database at all if you can.  That can be a little trickier with things like `Item.all` and associations, which are harder to wire up without either stubbing or persisting to the test DB.  Mocking and stubbing makes it easy, but also makes your tests a bit more brittle should the models change.

For the request spec, I'd create real DB objects and do something like this, using Capybara:

```
it "lists all items without a user_id" do
  visit foo_path
  current_path.should == foo_path
  page.should have_content(item1.name)
  page.should have_content(item2.name)
end
```

..and similar for the path with `user_id`.  Without knowing your data and how you're rendering it, I can't be more specific.  If you're using JSON, you should check the entire JSON response here.  I wouldn't check the JSON response in the controller spec, though; the controller's job is just to shuffle the data to the right view.  You can test the view in isolation too, and then test the whole end-to-end scenario in your request spec.

Answer (score 1):

For the controller spec, you'd set up mocks that will handle the authentication of the request.  You'd only want to test that if `params[:user_id]` is passed, then `@items` is set to the user items, and if not, then all items.

For the request spec, you will simply include some test to verify the process of authentication.

If you ask me, I'll verify the api response as a json in both tests.